# Is there any way to add health check alerts for bigquery project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking for some monitoring for my bigquery project so that I am alerted when project is not available or for any reason dataset is not found.

Comment: You want monitoring only for these two use cases?

Comment: Yes, that's the use case for now.

Comment: @DeepikaJuneja Were you able to achieve this? were you able to setup health check alerts for bigquery?